# How do I embed YouTube videos without black bars?

Tags: video, youtube, embed, fullscreen, vimeo

When I try to embed fullscreen YouTube or Vimeo videos I get black bars to the left and right on 16:9 monitor:

See attached screenshot: [image]

How do I embed videos like Vimeo do? Their fullscreen videos are always without black bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um.  Try uploading a 16x9 video instead of a 4x3 one.